# группировка в sql. ругается access

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT Товары.Наименование, [Заказы и продажи].Продано
FROM Товары INNER JOIN [Заказы и продажи] ON Товары.Код_товара = [Заказы и продажи].Код_товара
GROUP BY Товары.Наименование, [Заказы и продажи].Продано
HAVING ((([Заказы и продажи].Продано) Between 10 And 30));
```

задание звучит так:     Создайте запрос на языке SQL, возвращающий наименования товаров, проданных в количестве от 10 до 30, причем наименования товаров находится в таблице «Товары», а количество проданных товаров в таблице «заказы и продажи» и эти таблицы связаны между собой по полю «Код товара».

хочу сгруппировать чтобы наименования не повторялись, например Молоко Хлеб Молоко Кукуруза сейчас, а было  бы молоко хлеб кукуруза

код был сделан в access запросами и потом просмотрен. если пытаюсь сделать группировку по одному полю, то ругается, что наименование не часть агрегатной функции. как исправить не пойму

Comment: *проданных **в количестве** от 10 до 30* - где ж это самое количество считается-то?

Comment: там есть поле "продано" в которых содержится число являющееся количеством проданных товаров. и нужно выбрать те поля в которых соответственно от 10 до 30 число

Comment: А когда вы сгруппируете до наименования (что бы не повторялись), вот скажем у вас две записи "Молоко" в одной продано 20 в другой 10 что вы хотите показать в результате запроса в этой колонке ? Ведь строка то одна, одновременно и 10 и 20 показать невозможно. Можно например сумму =30 но для этого надо что бы была явно применена функция sum()

Comment: да, именно так оказывается и надо, спасибо!

Comment: Обратите внимание - если вам надо отфильтровать из исходных данных строки между 10 и 30 это надо делать в where. А вот если вам надо взять две записи Молоко 5 и 6, их сумма =11 и если вы вдруг хотите что бы именно эта сумма проверялась на 10-30, то тогда да, это должно быть в having но опять же надо явно брать сумму т.е. `sum(Продано) between ...`